# Why does my method to save a button click in a text document not work properly?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, jbutton

Hey I am currently working on a search engine and am encountering a problem: we have to implement an evaluation interface that notes down how relevant a response of our search engine to a given query is.

This is my method that is supposed to do that job, but doesnt give out any buttons or anything at all besides the search results. I would be very appreciative for any support

```
private void evaluation(String query, ArrayList<String> identities) {           
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String datum = df.format(date);
        File eval = new File(query+ datum+".txt");
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();  
        frame.setLayout(null);  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                     

            for(String id: identities) {                
                JButton b1 = new JButton(id + "-1");
                b1.setBounds(50,50,90, 50);  
                b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    private PrintWriter writerEval;
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                      {
                          try {
                                writerEval = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(eval, true)));
                                writerEval.println(datum  +", " + id+", 0");    
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                ioe.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (writerEval != null) {
                                    writerEval.flush();
                                    writerEval.close();
                                }
                      }
                      }});
                frame.add(b1);              
                JButton b2 = new JButton(id + "0");
                b2.setBounds(50,50,90, 50);
                b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    private PrintWriter writerEval;
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                      {
                          try {
                                writerEval = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(eval, true)));
                                writerEval.println(datum  +", " + id+", 0");    
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                ioe.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (writerEval != null) {
                                    writerEval.flush();
                                    writerEval.close();
                                }
                      }
                      }});
                frame.add(b2);
                JButton b3 = new JButton(id + "1");
                b3.setBounds(50,50,90, 50);
                b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                      private PrintWriter writerEval;
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                      {
                          try {
                                writerEval = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(eval, true)));
                                writerEval.println(datum  +", " + id+", 0");    
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                ioe.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (writerEval != null) {
                                    writerEval.flush();
                                    writerEval.close();
                                }
                      }
                      }});
                frame.add(b3);                              
            }

        frame.setSize(300,200);  
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment: thanks for the input, noted that I used frame.add(b1) three times! still, the problem stands that it doesnt give ANY output besides the search results

Comment: `null` Layout means that you have to set the position of the buttons manually to different locations, And the  `frame.setLayout(null);` needs to be before you add the buttons. Update your example.

Comment: okay i updated my example. frame.setLayout now stands before the part where i add the buttons. i have to look up how to use .setLayout correctly

Comment: Yes, you have to dynamically calculate the position or (the preferred way) you use a different kind of layout which does that automatically for you.

Comment: so it seems like i have to use JPanel.. any recommendations regarding that?
best case scenario would be 3 buttons per row

Comment: I added 
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
   contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

directly after creating the instance of JFrame

Comment: Check here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Did you verify that `identities` is not empty?

Comment: thanks second, i will take a look at it. and i have not verified it, no, gonna do that too now. thanks for the answers!

Comment: @VGR when i tried to sys.out the size of the array list i noticed that it doesnt even seem to execute that method. i think i have position it somewhere else in my code

Comment: Did you place the print statement before your `for` loop?